# ConvertNumber do JSF valores negativos

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Os valores monetários negativos, ao usar o conversor nativo do JSF, `<f:convertNumber type="currency"/>`, ficam com o caractere '`-`', antes do R$.

Por exemplo: `-R$ 56.134.726,99`

**.xhtml**

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{entidade.valorMonetário}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Existe alguma forma de resolver esse problema sem eu ter que criar o meu próprio Converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o problema em usar simplesmente:

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{entidade.valorMonetário}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

e o negativo(`'-'`) fica atrás do símbolo `R$`

ex: `-R$ 56.134.726,99`

Aplicando o seguinte pattern

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{entidade.valorMonetário}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="R$" locale="pt_BR" pattern="¤ ###,###,##0.00; ¤ -###,###,##0.00"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

O negativo(`'-'`) fica depois do símbolo `R$`.

ex: `R$ -56.134.726,99`

Comment: Se possível, desenvolva mais a explicação, explicar as partes da sua resposta, o que são cada atributo de <f:>, ¤, e como funcionam.? Da maneira redigida você simplesmente jogou códigos dizendo para aplicar tal *pattern*

Comment: Sim, melhorou muito a qualidade de sua resposta.